# Asp.net generation of local oauth token

Tags: asp.net, oauth, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to exchange an external oauth access token for a local one.

Everything seems to be working. However I can't succeed in generationg the local oath token.

I'm getting:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null.
```

On this line of code:

```
var accessToken = AltaiStartup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
```

This is the code responsible for generating the local token:
    private JObject GenerateLocalAccessTokenResponse(string userName, string userId)
        {

```
        var tokenExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity();

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, userId));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));


        var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(tokenExpiration),
        };

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);

        var accessToken = AltaiStartup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);

        JObject tokenResponse = new JObject(
                                    new JProperty("userName", userName),
              new JProperty("access_token", accessToken),
                                    new JProperty("token_type", "bearer"),
                                    new JProperty("expires_in", tokenExpiration.TotalSeconds.ToString()),
                                    new JProperty(".issued", ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc.ToString()),
                                    new JProperty(".expires", ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.ToString())
    );

        return tokenResponse;
    }
```

And this is my startup-class:

```
  public class AltaiStartup
{

    public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {


        // WebApi config
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // SimpleInjector
        var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();
        container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior = new ImportPropertySelectionBehavior();

        container.Verify();
        config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        // Setup Oauth
        ConfigureOAuth(app, container.GetInstance<IAuthModule>());

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);

    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, IAuthModule AuthModule)
    {

        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();


        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new AltaiAuthorizationServerProvider(AuthModule)
        };

        OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat = OAuthServerOptions.AccessTokenFormat;
        OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat = OAuthServerOptions.AccessTokenFormat;
        OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenProvider = OAuthServerOptions.AccessTokenProvider;
        OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationMode = OAuthServerOptions.AuthenticationMode;
        OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationType = OAuthServerOptions.AuthenticationType;
        OAuthBearerOptions.Description = OAuthServerOptions.Description;
        OAuthBearerOptions.SystemClock = OAuthServerOptions.SystemClock;

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seemed to solve it:

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```